# Linear wave superposition along a rope/string

Tags: waves, string, superposition

This question basically roots to fundamentals of waves which is quite difficult for me to visualize. Hope that I can clear out this confusion based on answers to this question

**Would be grateful if someone atleast verifies whether my own answer below is correct or not**

[image]

suppose the green line in the image is a string. black dots were drawn to represent particles along the string and the red/blue ones are the displaced(due to wave) particles. Lets say two waves emerged at the two ends of the string and met at the particle $g$. These two waves are of same amplitude and same frequency. Aftermath of this superposition is that all these particles get displaced in the opposite direction nut at equal height after a very small period of time of the meeting of the two waves at $g$ and will move on like that.[All these assumptions are made for a very short period of time. I know that all the particles will return to equilibrium as soon as the energy is transfered completely to succeding particles]

Now the thing I didn't get is the progression of waves even after nullification of waves at $g$. I know that waves aren't nullified but they superimpose in such a way that the particle where they are meeting won't oscillate at all. But how does a mechanical wave propagate? It obviously needs a medium to propagate which in our case is the string. lets say we wanted to create a crest. In order to create that we lifted $a$ at the height of $A$ from the equilibrium position. As soon as we lifted that particle we immediately pulled it down. Now the particles adjacent to $a$ will also get a pull during the lifting but when we pulled $a$ down $b$ didn't go down immediately rather due to inertia it did reach at the height $A$ too. Succeeding particles will face same phenomenon. so to propagate a wave we observed that the preceding particles need to oscillate to transfer that energy  to the succeeding ones through attraction, cohesion, adhesion or whatever. But what if a particle isn't oscillating? lets say particle $e$ is hold tightly so that it does not move at all. So it is unlikely that $f$ will oscillate rather it is more likely that the wave will reflect. **Will the wave actually reflect back? If it does reflect, how does that reflect?(I can not visualize this one too nor does it seem to me intuitively understandable.)** Lets forget holding anything and imagine that the two waves did meet at $g$. Now $g$ won't oscillate since these two waves are at opposite phase. so after the two waves end up  at $g$ before the inversion as shown in the video of the link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJbpXx8fMUk), **how does two waves again move from $g$ in two opposite direction? $g$ is supposed to remain static or oscillate but with a very low amplitude, how does it end up evolving waves of higher amplitude?**

For this reason I am facing a lot of difficulty in understanding standing waves(**how does wave propagate from nodal points if the particle at nodal point itself is not oscillating or is oscillating but with a very low amplitude?**). I have looked for many sites for clearing out this confusion but could not find any satisfying answer or maybe I am too dumb to understand.

Comment: You may wish to look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/211204/59023

Comment: I did get the answer to reflection @honeste_vivere but didn't get the part of superposition.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this type of answer. I thought of a way which might answer my own question but do not know whether this thought observation is correct or wrong.

[image]

According to above figure I have considered each  of these red dots as some designated segments of the rope/string, these pulses are of same amplitude and wavelength. **b** segment is being pulled upwards by the **a** segment and downwards by the **c** segment. And **d** segment is being pulled downwards and upwards by **e** and **c** respectively. There might come a moment when **a** and **e** will reach to the equilibrium(gray line) and **b** and **d** will reach o the height **a**. then **b** will be pulled downwards **a** and **c** again **d** will be pulled upwards by **e** and **c**. Now since **c** is not moving at all this will let **b** and **d** to go beyond the equilibrium. If **c** would have moved this wouldn't have happened, because if **c** moved upwards then the distance between **b** and **c** would have decreased and again at some point this would have increased but at the opposite direction that is **c** being upwards and **b** being downwards and would have negated the effect of inertia of **b** causing it to stop at equilibrium. But **c** isn't moving so **b** will move downwards beyond the equilibrium and **d** will move upwards beyond equilibrium. And this would look as if nothing happened, these two pulses are moving through each other even though they are actually reflecting about  **c**.